# Opening a new page and sending a restAPI call on click of button in react Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to react native, started learning yesterday.

So, far my file structure is this:

```
---Assets
   --- (some images)
---Screens
   ---WelcomeScreen.js
   ---Login.js
---app.js
---server.py  (contains my flask API implementations)
```

I would like to navigate from WelcomeScreen to Login screen on clicking the login or register button inside WelcomeScreen and also send a rest API call to my backend so that I can further process the info.

**app.js:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <WelcomeScreen />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
    }
})
```

**WelcomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import Login from './Login';
 

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
    return (

        <ImageBackground 
        style={styles.background}
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={require("../assets/bg.jpg")}>
        <Button
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(Login)}  //throwing error
        //TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')
        title="Login"
        color="#fc5c65"
        />
        <Button
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(Login)}  //throwing error
        //TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')
        title="Register"
        color="#4ecdc4"
        />
        </ImageBackground>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
    },
    loginButton:{
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#fc5c65'
    },
    registerButton:{
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#4ecdc4'
    },
})

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export default function Login() {
    return (
        <ImageBackground 
        style={styles.background}
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={require("../assets/splash.png")}>
        </ImageBackground>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
    },
    loginButton:{
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#fc5c65'
    },
    registerButton:{
        width: "100%",
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#4ecdc4'
    },
})
```

Now, from the WelcomeScreen.js,
I want to go to the login page upon clicking login button or register button and also send a restAPI call to the backend.

How do I do this??

Answer (score 1):

Navigation isn't always built in to react native. Primarily people use libraries to handle this smoothly. Based on your code, you've been following an example based on using `react-navigation` which you can read about [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started). Essentially you'll need nest all of your screens inside of special components from that library which will pipe the `navigation` prop through to your screen components.

In order to run the API calls, you can add those functions calls on a new line in each of the functions you are passing as the onPress prop. Alternatively, you could place a `useEffect` hook in your screen components to make the API call after the navigation has completed.

```
// in Login.js
export const Login = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    callAPI()
  }, []);
 ...
}
```